# Why did Kylo Ren say Rey would only get stronger on Starkiller Base?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, rey

In *The Force Awakens*, after **Rey** had escaped from the interrogation chair (and beat him in a contest of the Force), **Kylo Ren** said to one of his stormtroopers:

> *"She's just beginning to test her powers. The longer it takes to find her, the more dangerous she becomes."*

[image: "She's just beginning to test her powers. The longer it takes to find her, the more dangerous she becomes."]

What I want to know is:

---

1) Why was this? Did he believe that the longer Rey stayed on the planet, the stronger she grew in the Force?

2) Did Rey draw her powers from the kyber crystals within the planet?

3) If so, how did he know this? Had he experienced the same himself?

---

Furthermore, why did Kylo reveal this information to a stormtrooper? What was she supposed to do about it? The trooper surely sounds like a female so maybe, out-of-universe, at some point of production, he was supposed to be telling this fact to **Captain Phasma**...?

Comment: Is it actually established that starkiller base was ilum in the movies or novel?

Comment: @CBredlow - No. It hasn't been, nor in any of the supplementary materials.

Comment: @CBredlow As far as I know, only indirectly. The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary shows a map, with Starkiller Base Origin Point at the same location where Ilum is in the Legends maps.
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Canon_galaxy_map_Empire_mag.png
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:MainGalaxy.png

Comment: Want to answer this, @DVK-in-exile? ;)

Comment: This seems very broad, slightly opinion-based and there are three different questions here.

Comment: @Valorum Sorry, got a bit carried away thinking about all the options... :-)

Comment: @Essen - No need for apologies. Try to edit to refocus on your main thesis.

Comment: I think Kylo's point is that she's just found her powers, yet she's already broken free as well as defied *his* mental powers in a direct contest. He wants to "nip it in the bud" before she figures out how to do some more hectic shit.

Comment: What @Mooz said. She already managed to mind-trick James &^**& Bond. And to trick Kylo Ren into showing that he's a pretty-boy with attractive hair instead of a menacing Sith(ish) Lord(ling). And to see into his mind to discover that he (shocker) has Daddy Issues. Next thing, she'll be psychoanalyzing General Hux. Can't have that.

Comment: @Mikasa Pinata Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

I can't offer a cannon based answer, but can offer an answer based on my understanding of human nature, and what I would imagine someone in that universe might do under the same circumstances.

I would think that Kylo Ren was concerned that the longer it took to find her the more time she would have to test and, not so much master, but gain expertise in the use of those powers.

Obviously gifted, she was able to compel someone EARLY. Universal knowledge of the force would give her ideas of what she might be capable of. Creativity and necessity might force her to think of, and try, things she might not have thought of otherwise under structured tutelage. Therefore, the longer she was free to run throughout the facility free, the longer she had to strengthen her newfound abilities, and think of ways to use them.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, fine thinking. Kylo was indeed surprised by another Force-user with no training at all, and he didn't want to her to escape. Maybe he meant a larger perspective of time.